# Center two responsive columns with css

Tags: css, responsive-design, css-float, css-selectors

How do I center my two blog columns?

Please check my page here: `www.marianoshoes.com/demo/the-journal/`

I tried some CSS combinations but I couldn't achieve the result!

Thank you!

Comment: What exactly do you mean? Aren't they centered?

Comment: They are not centered. They may seem centered because my content are, as a small width. Took a screenshot in firebug: www.marianoshoes.com/demo/not_centered.png

Answer (score 1):

You need to center your li with text-align. But to make this work, you need to change float:left to display:inline-block. It would look something like this:

```
ul{
    text-align:center;
}
li{
    display:inline-block;
    //remove float:left
}
```

On your `li:nth-child(even)` you will also have to change the first value of `transform: translate3d(468px, 0px, 0px);` to 0, like so: `transform: translate3d(0px, 0px, 0px);`